# Passing Multiple Arguments to the Python __name__=="__main__"

Tags: python

I have python function getting called from `__main__` thats accepts 2 arguments. First one is an action and second one is switch name. I need the `__main__` to accept one keyword and multiple switches at the same time and call the function using multithreading as `function(action,switch1)` , `function(action,switch2)`, `function(action, switch3)` etc.....

Here is my code so far and Im unable to extract the host names one by one to call the function over and over again..Im yet to implement the multitreading but will do once Im able to extract various SWITCHNAMEs

```
if __name__=="__main__":
        import argparse
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Enter ACTION & SWITCHNAME")
        parser.add_argument('action')
        parser.add_argument('switch', nargs='*')
        args = parser.parse_args()
        for arg in vars(args):
            print getattr(args, arg)

            SanSwitchTasks.SupportSaveCollection(SWITCHNAME)
```

Comment: It's just an ordinary `if` statement. `sys.argv` has the same value whether or not `__name__` is set to `"__main__"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the problem is, just loop over the switches.

```
for switch in args['switch']:
    function(args['action'], switch)
```

Comment: for switch in args['switch']:
TypeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: Never mind..I got it ..  args = vars(parser.parse_args())
        for switch in args['switch']:
              print switch